How to model when header table has values?
I have following tables:
order header table: ordnum, orddate, customerID, cost_of_packing, cost_of_delivery
Order line table: ordnum, ordlinenum, productid, qty, price
Ordnum column is the common field between the above 2 tables.
Customer: customerID, customername
Product: productID, productname
How to model this data?
If I join order header and order lines tables, therefore make this into one fact table, then the costofpackaging and costofdelivery will duplicate for each row.
If I keep them as 2 separate fact tables, then I cannot connect them on ordnum column as this breaks the star schema design. Thus I can't report on order header and details.

Get rid of order header table entirely. Bring order dates and customer Ids to the order detail table, and allocate costs to the lines.
If you need to do line-level calculations, you will have to define cost allocation rules. For example, express costs as % of the order total value, and then multiply by the line amounts. That will make costs fully additive.
If costs are never considered at the line level, then simply park them at the first line of each order, and keep blanks at all other lines.
Edit:
I mocked up your data and model to show how it will look in practice.
Data model:

Mocked up Orders table with top-level numbers allocated to the first order line:

Top-line report looks like this:

Order detail report with drill-down to products:

DAX Measures:
line-level:
Order Qty = SUM(Orders[Qty])

Order Amount = SUMX(Orders, Orders[Price]*Orders[Qty])

top-level:
Order Delivery Cost =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Orders[Delivery Cost] ),
    REMOVEFILTERS ( Orders[Product ID] )
)

Combined top and line level calculations:
Order Total  = [Order Amount] + [Order Delivery Cost]

As you can see, the model is simple, and the calculations are intuitive and performant. The only thing that looks a bit strange is the blank in delivery costs, but that's the price you'll have to pay for not allocating.

Unfortunately there isn't a fixed rule to allocate cost to line level

That's the root of you problem: line level numbers and order level numbers are at a different level of detail. You have to resolve this one way or another - either roll up line-level numbers to the top level, or allocate down. Any "solution" that ignores this mismatch is swiping the real problem under the rug. If you don't have a rule for the allocation, establish one.

Rather how about I keep them separate fact tables, and create a dimension with distinct OrdNum. Then make a 1:M relation between this dim and each fact table. Therefore user can analyse the header, and detail as well as drill through from header to detail via the common dimension.

The problem with this design is that other dimensions won't be shared (product, date, customer). This will make analysis and DAX code very cumbersome and inefficient. Besides, it still does not address the level of detail mismatch. For example, let's say business asks you a question: show me net profit by product. How would you do it? In your suggested design, you won't be able to answer questions like that.

Assuming there's no requirement to show net profile by product then is this a good model? I'm sure this is a common scenario wherein order level values cannot be assigned to detail level. How do model developers handle such scenario?

Making Order a dimension is a bad practice. Orders are essentially transactions, which means they are facts, not dimensions. In practice, order dimension will constantly grow, and eventually become very tall. Proper Start schema requires dimensions to be short and wide, and fact table tall and narrow (tall dimensions kill query performance). The best practice is to allocate header level values down to the line level (read this white paper from Kimball (pdf file): https://www.kimballgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/2013.09-Kimball-Dimensional-Modeling-Techniques11.pdf

Ideally, business should give you proper allocation rules. If not, fake them. In the worst case, just assign header values to the first line, and null to the others. To get shipping costs then is just a simple summation (as long as you are not filtering the report by product - if so, use "removefilters" on product). Such model is superior to the one you described in every aspect.

How about header values to be assigned to each line, and then I use SUMX(VALUES(table[ordnum]), CALCULATE(MAX(cost_of_delivery))) for the value, therefore I have one fact table.

Sure, but why do you want to make it difficult? Iterator with CALCULATE means a loop with context transition, which is very expensive. With allocation, it's just SUM(cost of delivery).

I just cannot allocate. At best I get your point that I need to allocate all of it to one detail row. I'm thinking about this.

if I do allocate entire sale header value to one of the detail records, then what exactly is the limitation of such a model?

The only limitation is product. Without a proper allocation, your analysis of the top-line numbers will be incorrect if products are filtered. You can solve this either by having a dedicated report for the top line calculations, or by using REMOVEFILTERS on product in measures that involve top-line numbers. .
In any case, this is no different from other models you considered - they all have the same issue, plus they would require convoluted and slow DAX.

@variable: I made an edit to my answer to show you how it looks in practice.

Thank you for taking the time for detailed answer giving me clarity. So removefilters is useful only if the measure is used alongside a Product and non top level detail.

Yes, and also if you put product on a slicer that filters the report (because if a product is selected, top line costs will be incorrect).

Good work RADO - upvoted.

@rado - when I allocate the header level values to one of the detail rows, then should the other rows be given the value 0 or empty/null?

Either one is fine; I prefer to use blanks because reports look cleaner.

Connect them into a single table and then use DISTINCT(). This is just the nature of header/detail structures in star schemas. The alternative is connecting to fact tables and when you connect two very large cardinality tables, the performance of the rest of the model will be terrible.

What do you mean by connect them into a single table?

Merge the header and details table into one large table. You will have duplicate values for each header row.

Ok in this case the cost of packaging and cost of delivery values will duplicate for each order detail item for an order. How do I expose these values to the end user? For example - I can't use AVG or MAX as that will give misleading value. I see you mention using DISTINCT. How exactly to use this for my purpose?

You will need to write measures in the same way you do for sales. Sales is simple as SUM ( table[column] ) whilst deliveries would be something like SUMX(VALUES(table[ordnum], cost_of_delivery). There is a very good article here which explains why merging is the right thing to do from a star schema perspective. https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/header-detail-vs-star-schema-models-in-tabular-and-power-bi/

How about this - say I keep the header and detail as separate fact tables. And create a new dimension table containing distinct list of OrdNum. And connect this dim to both fact tables.

By the way, shouldn't your above formula be: SUMX(VALUES(table[ordnum]), CALCULATE(MAX(cost_of_delivery)))

Actually, it should probably be something like this: SUMX(SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[Order], 'Table'[Delivery Cost]), 'Table'[Delivery Cost])

You can try creating a dimension but you will probably hit some further issues when creating your measures or visualisations later on. I've found the SQLBI is usually the best practice.

what issues do you see with having a dimension like that please?

It really depends on your model. Try prototyping what you intend and if it isn't working, you can remodel.

David - on what based do you decide if I must use SUMX(VALUES(table[ordnum]), CALCULATE(MAX(cost_of_delivery))) or SUMX(SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[Order], 'Table'[Delivery Cost]), 'Table'[Delivery Cost]) . I have read the sqlbi article you shared but I'm not understanding how to write the DAX when header/detail table is combined into one table.

Both are fine. There are usually lots of ways of solving the same problem in DAX and the issues don't present themselves until you're testing against your own specific model. I would go with the first one in the first instance.

By first one I believe you mean my version? Also, could you point me to any articles on how to write such DAX to handle such things. I know intermediate DAX but I need to learn it from this angle. Please give me some pointers.

Yes, your version. Intermediate DAX should be sufficient. I don't know specific articles but usually SQLBI have everything DAX covered. The videos on youtube for SQLBI are also excellent.

If you get stuck, just post a new question with the issue
