How can I get my power bi aggregation month/year table to share a calendar dimension with a daily detail table?
I have a rather complex Semantic Model with over 20 dimensions. At the heart of it I have a Direct Query detail table and an imported aggregation table as my facts.  The detail table has daily dates and the aggregation table is by month.  These work great if I have a separate month dimension to my day dimension.
However, that is not very user friendly.
So how can I combine the date dimension so they both use the same dimension but if a user selects month then it aggregates and if they select day it doesn't.
I have Fact which I count rows for number of tickets.
Then I have used_date as my calendar and use_month as my month dimension.

I can get this to work if the 2 dimensions are separated.  I have connected month to the calendar date dimension but the model no longer uses aggregation then.
Found this link and attempted the suggestion #2.  Created a new id that is BOM and joined it to the date time table.  Used Manage Aggregations to poitn the new custom field to the datetime ID on the detail table.  But still not aggregating.
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Aggregation-by-month-connect-to-date-dimension/td-p/3585937
As per RADO's request here is a snippet of what I would like to create.  I can create summarized by month/year reports but what I'm looking for now is a drillthrough report that users can see detailed data.  Which I'm running into a couple of issues with.
I would like it to look something like this.  Where it shows by creation date and hour how many tickets were created in that hour.  Or by Date if not by hour.
With the way I've designed the aggregation it shows it all by the first of the month.
If I try to drag in an ID field I get a 1,000,000 error as well.  Which is yet another issue to troubleshoot.
I have RLS that would theoretically reduce the rows but that doesn't help with my detailed tables.

The dax i am testing with is simply:  Number of Tickets = countrows(FactTable)
Sample Data:

Fact data (Simplified by removing time)

Aggregation Table

Would show from higher level aggregation of Number of tickets and completed

Which I would drill down into detailed view that goes by date.  If I agg by BOM this table is just the first of month instead of this detail.


in the aggregated fact table, instead of months use the first (or the last) date of the month; i.e, instead of 2024-04, use 2024-04-01. Then you can use one date table for both fact tables.

Hi @RADO I did this but now I have the problem that if a user decides to view the information by date it auto summarizes by the 1st day of the month instead of showing a daily count.  Is there a way to force it to show detail for anything less than a  month?

I don't understand the problem. Can you add screenshots of the reports you are trying to build and explain how they should look like ideally? Also, show any relevant DAX measures you are using in these reports.

Hi @RADO I added a picture and more context.  Let me know if it helps or just confuses things more!  Thanks for any help you can provide.  I have turned on auto aggregations and am seeing how it operates while I try to figure out my manual aggregation problem.

Well, it confused things even more for me. These blanked out pictures don't provide much information. To debug DAX, it's essential to understand data, relations, and the construction of the visuals (which fields are used from which tables). I can't figure these out from your post. I understand you need to protect private data; so, instead, create a simplified report with mocked-up (fake) data that clearly illustrate your issue. For example, how I did it for another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78351229/how-to-model-when-header-table-has-values/78357211#78357211

Ha!  Sorry about that!  I tried again and added some pictures.  Let me know if this helps!!
